# How to access data passed to the jade during compilation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, pug

Here is the code I've written in `Gruntfile.js` where I pass `JSON` file to Jade.

```
 compile: {
            files: {
             // some files
            },
            options: {
                pretty: true,

                // Passing .Json file as data to jade
                data: grunt.file.readJSON("./src/jade/config.json")
            }
```

How do I get access to data in .jade files? I've looked around but couldn't found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you pass is a map of key-value pairs. You can then use a Jade syntax to use those values by the associated key names.

For instance, if data would be:

```
{ "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2" }
```

Then the following template:

```
div= key1
div Some text #{key2}
```

Would render:

```
<div>value1</div>
<div>Some text value2</div>
```

The reference for this is in the Jade documentation, specifically in the [string interpolation chapter](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/).